# Classpath Scanning in Spring Boot Jar Not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath

I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Pipeline  {
  String id ();
  String name ();
  boolean visible () default true;
  String role () default "USER";
}
```

Which I use on interfaces within a Spring Boot App with nested jars:

```
@Pipeline(id="my-pipeline", name="My Pipeline")
public interface Echo {
  ...
}
```

My project structure:

```
parent-boot-project
   |
   --- plugin1.jar 
   --- plugin2.jar <--- interfaces are here
   --- ...
```

Next, I use lukehutch's fast-classpath-scanner to scan for them:

```
new FastClasspathScanner(BASE_PACKAGE)
    .matchClassesWithAnnotation(PIPELINE_ANNOTATION, aProcessor)
    .verbose()
    .scan();
```

Works great on my IDE (eclipse) but not when I build the jar. Tried messing around with the classpath but to no avail. Anyone ran into something like that?

Comment: FastClasspathScanner makes assumptions that don't hold true with nested jars. Why not use Spring Framework's classpath scanning support instead?

Comment: I tried using `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` but it seems to only work with beans whereas in my case these are just annotated interfaces. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

FastClasspathScanner has been renamed ClassGraph, and now has full Spring Boot scanning support.